# Webscraping BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a schoolproject where I have to scrape about 88 000 companies in Belgium. Some websites take a bit longer to find a word on the site, so I assume this is just a bigger website. However, when I get to the website of DHL ([www.dhl.com](http://www.dhl.com)), my program does not do anything. Is there a reason this is not possible or can a company disable scraping their website? I do not think there is anything wrong in my code, but I've placed it below.
The variable websites is just an array with all the URL's of the companies.

```
counter = 0
url = ""
for url in websites:
  counter += 1
  word = 'de'

  print(f'{counter}: {url}')

  try:
    r = req.get('http://'+url.strip())
    r.encode = 'utf-8'

    html_content = r.text

    soup = bs(html_content, 'lxml')
    to_search = soup.find_all(text = lambda text : text and word.lower() in text)

    if len(to_search) > 0:
      print(f'\tamount of "{word}" on website: {len(to_search)}')
    else:
      print(f'\t"{word}" never occured')

  except:
    print(f'\t{url} is unavailable')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, companies can prevent scrapping by detecting a bot. If you go to the dhl site though, it seems to redirect so not sure if that's the issue. When I run you script, it just stalls.

This does also raise another question though. When you search for the word `"de"`, are you specifically looking for ONLY `'de'`? Because as you have it coded, it will return any string that contains `'de'`. For example, with this code for the dhl.com site, it finds `''bazadebezolkohpepadr="1231685289"''` as 1 of the 26 `'de'`'s it counts.

And to that point, that will also include any finctions or scripts in the html as well. For example, this also is counted as a '"de"` word for dhl.com:

```
'!function(a){var e="https://s.go-mpulse.net/boomerang/",t="addEventListener";if("True"=="True")a.BOOMR_config=a.BOOMR_config||{},a.BOOMR_config.PageParams=a.BOOMR_config.PageParams||{},a.BOOMR_config.PageParams.pci=!0,e="https://s2.go-mpulse.net/boomerang/";if(window.BOOMR_API_key="RSVGU-547KJ-ZUMZD-ZW27F-P4RHY",function(){function n(e){a.BOOMR_onload=e&&e.timeStamp||(new Date).getTime()}if(!a.BOOMR||!a.BOOMR.version&&!a.BOOMR.snippetExecuted){a.BOOMR=a.BOOMR||{},a.BOOMR.snippetExecuted=!0;var i,_,o,r=document.createElement("iframe");if(a[t])a[t]("load",n,!1);else if(a.attachEvent)a.attachEvent("onload",n);r.src="javascript:void(0)",r.title="",r.role="presentation",(r.frameElement||r).style.cssText="width:0;height:0;border:0;display:none;",o=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],o.parentNode.insertBefore(r,o);try{_=r.contentWindow.document}catch(O){i=document.domain,r.src="javascript:var d=document.open();d.domain=\'"+i+"\';void(0);",_=r.contentWindow.document}_.open()._l=function(){var a=this.createElement("script");if(i)this.domain=i;a.id="boomr-if-as",a.src=e+"RSVGU-547KJ-ZUMZD-ZW27F-P4RHY",BOOMR_lstart=(new Date).getTime(),this.body.appendChild(a)},_.write("<bo"+\'dy onload="document._l();">\'),_.close()}}(),"".length>0)if(a&&"performance"in a&&a.performance&&"function"==typeof a.performance.setResourceTimingBufferSize)a.performance.setResourceTimingBufferSize();!function(){if(BOOMR=a.BOOMR||{},BOOMR.plugins=BOOMR.plugins||{},!BOOMR.plugins.AK){var e=""=="true"?1:0,t="",n="uxq4jklij32vkyqodtiq-f-5a918ce10-clientnsv4-s.akamaihd.net",i="false"=="true"?2:1,_={"ak.v":"32","ak.cp":"640765","ak.ai":parseInt("326248",10),"ak.ol":"0","ak.cr":100,"ak.ipv":4,"ak.proto":"http/1.1","ak.rid":"1eef41a0","ak.r":42169,"ak.a2":e,"ak.m":"a","ak.n":"essl","ak.bpcip":"165.225.196.0","ak.cport":60467,"ak.gh":"23.52.43.86","ak.quicv":"","ak.tlsv":"tls1.3","ak.0rtt":"","ak.csrc":"-","ak.acc":"bbr","ak.t":"1645092049","ak.ak":"hOBiQwZUYzCg5VSAfCLimQ==gPk5vdO2N+xaMvOHluPHPA75P2qfqUmFzBjJVMEHxXiQzYo6BKsg3x+M21NSbrw9cCziPvIOGYUIJBB4srzYCVE+S3n8bUaeN3xk/+pwl6+CHMsGzVTAqySt3i0ewJ1GI5g6CypA2BL8kALrH1Z8sCNqZy0eMS1nmkOjppm315f4Qf+l8qhUvekcsNZ3NALIP0UqjlcEZtDpHsWEC+AoFQQTILEGMxqi4IctzOqS3RG+5KW2/TQ7YbksSvp0tOo9JIjguIAqM2gK8d/uOsFF2CIlIYFYtXQCoDnlosdxnVQjkIGLqOVcM81NauDexVgIRgCIbQWCO1VA2ZuuapLm5Jc7Noh83C3XodGjRNlS9oiLRZT7YI+z9GVtfANw8nVQn7TMhIt8F9KlMmzcHkKEwBFhXYozOkhx0YluLmLTaj8=","ak.pv":"278","ak.dpoabenc":"","ak.tf":i};if(""!==t)_["ak.ruds"]=t;var o={i:!1,av:function(e){var t="http.initiator";if(e&&(!e[t]||"spa_hard"===e[t]))_["ak.feo"]=void 0!==a.aFeoApplied?1:0,BOOMR.addVar(_)},rv:function(){var a=["ak.bpcip","ak.cport","ak.cr","ak.csrc","ak.gh","ak.ipv","ak.m","ak.n","ak.ol","ak.proto","ak.quicv","ak.tlsv","ak.0rtt","ak.r","ak.acc","ak.t","ak.tf"];BOOMR.removeVar(a)}};BOOMR.plugins.AK={akVars:_,akDNSPreFetchDomain:n,init:function(){if(!o.i){var a=BOOMR.subscribe;a("before_beacon",o.av,null,null),a("onbeacon",o.rv,null,null),o.i=!0}return this},is_complete:function(){return!0}}}}()}(window);'
```

A few things I'd change here:

1. change to `'https://'`
2. include user agent in the headers
3. include the timeout parameter in the request (doesn't fix the issue other than your code won't hang

With that being said, the code bellow found `amount of "de" on website: 21` for dhl:

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

websites = ['www.dhl.com']
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}


counter = 0
url = ""
for url in websites:
  counter += 1
  word = 'de'

  print(f'{counter}: {url}')

  try:
    r = req.get('https://'+url.strip(), headers=headers, timeout=10)
    r.encode = 'utf-8'

    html_content = r.text

    soup = bs(html_content, 'lxml')
    to_search = soup.find_all(text = lambda text : text and word.lower() in text)

    if len(to_search) > 0:
      print(f'\tamount of "{word}" on website: {len(to_search)}')
    else:
      print(f'\t"{word}" never occured')

  except:
    print(f'\t{url} is unavailable')
```

**Output:**

```
amount of "de" on website: 21
```